# Не понимаю почему не срабатывает скрипт?

Tags: javascript, функции, циклы

```js
function getDigitsSum(num) {
  var str = String(num);
  var arr = str.split('');
  var sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var sum += Number(arr[i]);
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(getDigitsSum(123));
```

Пишет ошибку в теле цикла. Что там не так, подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: Какую именно ошибку пишет?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token += .

Comment: Просто уберите лишний var. Кстати, переменная i у вас глобальная.

Comment: Да, я уже заметила! Большое спасибо!)

Answer (score 1):

У вас переменная sum определена уже выше.

Попробуйте так:

```
function getDigitsSum(num) {
  var str = String(num);
  var arr = str.split('');
  var sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += Number(arr[i]);
  }
  return sum;
}
alert(getDigitsSum(123));
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! А я уже всю голову сломала :D

Comment: Не за что, попробуйте использовать es6 в своем обучение ;)